How to "properly" combine left and right hand and foot strikes
What is the proper flow of combinations of hand and foot strikes, in sports like  kickboxing or MT?
For example in boxing, the beginners are usually taught that after a right cross your weight should be on your left foot so you can push off your left foot while executing the left hook thus putting the kinetic energy generated by the foot into your hook.
How does this work for kickboxing? I started kickboxing about 2 months ago (it is awesome btw) and I still can't really figure it out.
For example, I threw a right cross and the weight is on my left foot. Basically I can mentally justify throwing both kicks:

Left kick - same idea as in boxing, putting my weight behind the kick
Right kick - since my weight is in my left foot, I'm more stable standing on the left foot and executing a right kick.

I know there is no "proper" way per se, the choice is dependant on the  situation during the fight, but at least for a total beginner there has to be a way that makes sense physically, kinetically.

Let's say you're in a typical boxing stance, left leg forward, guarding at the face with both hands. You throw a right cross. Your weight is now on your lead left foot, by about 60%. Your back right foot's heel is lifted up, and there's about 40% of weight on it.
The question is: Which leg do you want to kick with now, in such a way that's easiest or quickest?
And the answer is that since your hips are already turning for that right cross to punch out, and since your back foot is already lifted somewhat off the ground, it means your back leg is now ready to kick in the follow-up.
For you to, instead, kick with the left lead foot, what you'll need to do is to shift your weight back to your back foot entirely. And then as you're doing that, you lift your left lead leg up and kick out. The amount of force this generates is far less than the amount of force generated by doing a kick with the right foot. And that's because of the amount distance the kick travels (momentum) as well as the use of the waist to add force.
Now, which is faster? You could argue the front leg kick would be faster, because it has less distance to travel. But you could also argue that the back leg's kick will be faster, because you don't need to shift any weight. You're already moving in that direction.
In general, I think for most people, the back leg will be faster, just because it's already in flight right behind that punch. There's no having to shift weight first. And as an added bonus, it's also much more powerful.
And while your opponent is eating that right cross (or dodging it), your back leg's kick is coming in from the same general angle, but a lot lower. It's easy for your opponent to miss that follow-up kick, because they're looking at your right hand. And their hands are up to guard as well, so they can't see very well what's going on. Your kick is coming in low, so they can't easily switch their guard downwards, too.
But, if you were to kick using the front leg, instead, it requires you to pull back with your body. Your arms will pull back, and shoulders will turn. That is easy for an opponent to detect.
Now, obviously there's more to it than just flow. There's decoying and strategy. There's making someone drop their guard. There's side-stepping and angling off. There's looking for habits and vulnerabilities, holes in defenses. Etc. Sometimes the best technique to throw is one that isn't the most powerful or fast in a particular situation. But that's beyond the scope of this question.
Hope that helps.

Great answer! So would you say that again for a total beginner it would make sense to kick from the same side as your opening punch? Basically left hand + left kick and right hand + right kick?

@ruslaniv Yes, in general that's probably true. It's about how your shoulders and waist are turned, and how your weight is distributed on your feet. Even when you do a jab punch, with 50/50 weight distribution on the legs and no hip rotation, the shoulder of that jab punch comes forward on that side. To then kick with the opposite side requires pulling that same shoulder back, which means you have to do more work than if you kicked with the same leg. So I think it holds true in general.

@ruslaniv There are exceptions to that rule, by the way. What if you're doing a spinning backfist with the right arm? Then following it with a left leg round kick would work better than a right leg round kick if your weight was forward on your right leg after the spin and if your backfist did not connect. If it connected, then you throw a right leg kick. If your weight was on your back leg, then you kick with the front leg instead. It can get tricky when you start adding different scenarios. But you'll know what to do as you get more experience. It will become obvious to you.
